# Implement search function as eBay does it for Android

Tags: android

I would like to implement a search function in my android app. I sow this on eBay android mobile app and the search is really fast and smooth.

Do you know how is this done on the mobile phone side and on the server?
Any example project similar to this one ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I used the soap protocole and the XMLPullParser on the phone's side. The search is fast.